Flask and Fetch POST Request
I am trying to send POST request but I get 500 error, its second day and i keep trying to solve it,
please help
Flask:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/tasks/today')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html', action='Мой день')


@app.route('/')
def redirect_to_homepage():
    return redirect('/tasks/today')

@app.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_input_text():
    print('Function worked!')

app.run()

Js:
let user = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
};
  
let response = fetch('/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
});

Thank you for any help

Your endpoint returns no response, throwing an error is correct. Communication in this form always consists of a request, which is answered with a response from the server. Furthermore, it is unclear why both GET and POST are allowed within the route definition.

Try this one
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/tasks/today")
def homepage():
    return render_template("index.html", action="Мой день")


@app.route("/")
def redirect_to_homepage():
    return redirect("/tasks/today")


@app.route("/post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_input_text():
    return jsonify({"message": "hello world"})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

If you ecounter error after that cause CORS try to install Flask-CORS
and update your code like this
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)


@app.route("/tasks/today")
def homepage():
    return render_template("index.html", action="Мой день")


@app.route("/")
def redirect_to_homepage():
    return redirect("/tasks/today")


@app.route("/post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_input_text():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return jsonify({"message": "this is post method"})

    return jsonify({"message": "this is get method"})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

